# systemd CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY specified in LoadCredential= is not being passed through ExecStart command line

Tags: 20.04, systemd

I have the following systemd config file `salt_server.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Salt Sensor Service
After=mysql.service
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitIntervalSec=10

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=salt_sensor_service
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=salty
LoadCredential=credentials.json:/home/salty/private/salty_credentials.json
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/salt_server -credentials=${CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY}/credentials.json -log_level=debug
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
ProtectSystem=strict
ProtectHome=true
PrivateUsers=true
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The command line resulting from the `ExecStart` line is

`/usr/local/bin/salt_server -credentials=/credentials.json -log_level=debug`

i.e. the `${CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY}` is an empty string. What am I doing wrong? I've tried various combinations of `Environment=` and `PassEnvironment=` but can't get it to work.

I've also tried `$CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY` and pretty much a load of other no-hope options.

Note that the credentials file and folder both exist and are readable by the user `salty`

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your systemd version (as shown by `systemctl --version` for example)? The "credentials" logic appears to have been introduced in 247 whereas afaik Ubuntu 20.04 ships with version 245

Comment: Nice catch! I am indeed on 245, I'll work out how to upgrade. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Bah, looks like upgrading systemd is basically not worth the hassle so I'm stuck with a hard coded path for now, thanks!